# CSS tabindex click hide main div

Tags: css

I am trying to make a tabindex menu with css.

This is my **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/kbuqj)** from codepen.io

When you click the red div from demo then the bubble menu will opening. But when you click the text then the bubble div not hidding.

How can i do when clicked the `.hid` class to hide `.eddel` ?

I know i can do it with jquery but i want to learn if i can do it with CSS.

```
<div tabindex="0" class="p_change">
    <ul class="eddel">
        <li class="hid">TEXT1</li>
        <li class="hid">TEXT2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.p_change {
margin-left:515px;
 position:absolute;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.p_change:before {
    content: "";

}
.p_change:focus {
    pointer-events: none;

}

.p_change:focus .eddel {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.eddel {
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.5s;
}

.p_change.no-pointer-events {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}

.p_change.no-visibility .eddel {
    visibility: visible !important;
    display: none;
}

.p_change.no-visibility:focus .eddel {
    display: block;
}

.p_change.no-opacity .eddel {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.p_change {
outline: 0;
margin-top:10px;
}
.p_change:before {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
.eddel {
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: rgba(235,235,235,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2cbdf2 0%,#fafafa 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2cbdf2 0%,#fafafa 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2cbdf2 0%,#fafafa 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2cbdf2 0%,#fafafa 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #2cbdf2 0%,#fafafa 0%,#f5f5f5 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0;
    width:80px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
}
.eddel a{
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
  font-family:'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000;
    }

/* arrow for the expanding part */
.eddel:after 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -9px;
left: 47px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 7px 8px;
border-color: #d8dbdf transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
}


.eddel:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 7px 8px;
    border-color: #fafafa transparent;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    left:47px;
    z-index:1;
}
.eddel li {
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:25px;
    text-indent:5px;
    padding:0;
}
.eddel li:hover {
    background:#3b5998;
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#FFF;
    }
.eddel li:hover a {   color: #FFF; }
.p_change {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Will the li elements be anchors? It will solve the problem autmatically... :P

Comment: @JacekKowalewski What do you mean? I don't understand :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.eddel` is inside `.p_change`. Then when you click it, `.p_change` still have the `:focus`. The solution I propose you is change a bit the HTML structure, like:

```
<h1>Please click the red div</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div tabindex="0" class="p_change"></div>
    <ul class="eddel">
        <li class="hid">TEXT1</li>
        <li class="hid">TEXT2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can use `.p_change:focus + .eddel` instead `.p_change:focus .eddel` as selector.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/zthnwr2h/1/)

Note: The `.container` is to handle position properly :)

Comment: Dear your code is working fine but can you check this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/KpQewO) for me because same think is not working in this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/KpQewO)

Comment: @innovation You need to put `.pr_type` out of `.p_change`. See [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tdj2902r/).

Comment: I can not put `.pr_type` out of `.p_change` because of i am using some jquery code for that. If i change like that then my Jquery ajax code not working on that time.

Comment: You can set a `tabindex` in `.pr_icon`, like `<div class="pr_icon" tabindex="1">`, and then use it as focussable element instead `.p_change`. Check a [new working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tdj2902r/1/).

Comment: then my ajax post method not working on that time :( [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/KpQewO)

Comment: I'm playing with your demo for a while, and my conclusion is that when you click on any element while another has the `:focus`, you only are "unfocus" the element. For example in [this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/umsghzau/1/) when you click an element of list an alert is showed, but if you click the red box, and then click an element of list, nothing happens. You should ask a new question for this issue ;)

Comment: it means when you click the red div the red div id is not selecting. My ajax code working fine without your css. But if i use your CSS then id is not selecting.

Comment: So how can I do it with js

Comment: "So how can I do it with js" it's another question, please post it and I'm sure you will get a fast answer :)

Comment: please help me Dear. My english is not well for that question. I still try to ask but som user give me -vote :( and i deleted my question. You are a good helper. Please help.

Comment: Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/tdj2902r/3/), the code is very simple. Note that with this you don't need most of your CSS code. Hope this help :)